# Date object changes along with device settings? (Swift 3)

Tags: ios, swift, date

A very simple question, but it still seems to be very hard to find an answer to it as none of the threads I found on Stack are what I'm looking for: is there a way to use a `Date()` object to get the actual date and time (perhaps from a server) instead of the date and time set on the user's device?

I want to have a `Timer()` object counting down to a certain time, for example today 6PM. If it's 3PM, the timer will show there are 3 hours left, but if I go to my settings and set the time 2 hours forward to 5PM, the timer in my app will now show there is only 1 hour left. I don't want this. I don't want the date/time on the device to influence the date/time representations in my app. I want my app to show me the actual unchangeable date/time from the Apple servers (which I'm pretty sure should exist somewhere in the iOS environment since it's possible to set your device's date/time settings to 'Automatic' which makes your device show the server time rather than a custom set date/time).

Like I said, very simple question, but I wanted to be absolutely sure I'm not misunderstood, because a lot of the commenters on the other threads gave some useless, unrelated answer. I really hope it's possible to do this with the tools provided by `UIKit` or any other Swift standard SDK, even though I fear for the worst (that I need to implement a third-party framework to achieve this).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't achieve this with standard apple tools. You should request server time via the network, and if the device is "offline" you can't do anything unless blocking user access to app functionality.

Better and simpler way to deny users from setting time forward (to receive some daily rewards) is tracking "in game" time and set something like: user MUST use the app at least 10 minutes (from the last day reward) before he can take the new day reward.

This way scrolling time forward would not be so fun. And most users wouldn't do this.

Comment: PS: you can track "in game" time using Timer functionality or perform(selector:afterDelay:). This two methods would not be affected by time forwarding. (But they are working only while app is active)

Comment: Ah, that's too bad :( It's actually kinda weird that you need internet connection to get server time, since Apple can show you server time on your device by setting Date and Time settings to Automatic, EVEN WHEN THE DEVICE IS NOT CONNECTED TO THE INTERNET. I think it's poor service that they don't allow iOS developers access to this Automatic date/time data. Doesn't seem like that's too much asked, does it? Anyway, thanks for the answer. I'll go look for a third party framework or I will just have to request date/time from the server-side of my connection.